# Null Config Useloggin issue in Xubuntu 16.04, Firefox browser

Tags: 16.04, networking, firefox, configuration, ebooks

I'm working in a school where all the computers have Xubuntu 16.04; I personally installed and set all the computers myself. All the computers have flash plugins and restricted extras, but only one computer has a strange issue: everytime I try to access a Pearson website (with texts, images, videos ecc.ecc.) through Firefox, a strange message pops up in a window.
I'm writing the error in the following lines:

```
 null
CONFIG::USELOGGING is set to true. Showing verbose error mesage.
faultString: Send failed
faultDetail: Channel. Connect. Failed error
NetConnection. Call. Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: "http://view.ebookplus.pearsoncmg.com:80/ebook/messagebroker/amf"
 faultCode: Client. Error. MessageSend
```

Hopefully someone can help me.